# merge three images with Tensorflow with indices

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, max-pooling

I have a problem with using Tensorflow. I have four images with their corresponding indices. I want to make an image from them. I tried for loops, tf.gather, tf.assign, and so on but all show error. If somebody help me, it would be really appreciated. I explain my question with one small example:
We have 4 tensors and their indices from tensor tf.ktop function: (I write like MATLAB for just for simplicity)

`a = [1, 2; 5, 6]   a_idx = [0, 1; 2, 3]
 b = [3, 4; 7, 8]   b_idx = [0, 1; 2, 3]
 c = [9, 10; 13, 14]   c_idx = [0, 1; 2, 3]
 d = [11, 12; 15, 16]   d_idx = [0, 1; 2, 3]`

I am looking for a big image from a, b, c, and d and their indices like:

`image = [a b; c d]
 image = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8;9 10, 11, 12;13, 14, 15, 16]`

In python I have something like:

```
a, a_idx, b, b_idx, c, c_idx, d, d_idx

n_x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 4, 4, 1]))

n_patches = tf.extract_image_patches(
    n_x,
    [1, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "SAME"
)
```

So, n_patches is 4 tensors and I need to put a to d values to each patch corresponding to a_idx to d_idx. Its really easy for me in MATLAB or Numpy to do that using for loop but in tensorflow I can not

Comment: easier example is that, we have values = [2, 5; 4 6], indices = [0, 3; 2, 1] then I am looking for image = [2 0 0 0; 0 0 0 5; 0 0 6 0; 4 0 0 0]. Is there any body with the same question? help of tensorflow website is really weak and its for professional people not for others.

Comment: After many search it seems that scatter_nd can help but still I am not sure about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments, I suspect you made a tiny error in your desired output, `image`.

I interpret that you want is given

```
values = np.array([[2, 5],\
                   [4, 6]])
indices = np.array([[0, 3],\
                    [2, 1]])
```

your result would be

```
[[2. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 6. 0. 0.]]
```

So you want to obtain a sort of one hot encoded matrix, but with values corresponding to given indices. This can be obtained like so:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([[2, 5],\
                   [4, 6]])
indices = np.array([[0, 3],\
                    [2, 1]])

# Make a matrix with only zeros
n_hots = np.zeros_like((indices))
# Now row 0,1,2 and 3 should have values corresponding to the
# indices. That is we should first "unpack" the values and indices:
indices=indices.ravel()
values=values.ravel()
# values are now: [2,5,4,6]
# indices are now: [0,3,2,1]
# values:
# n_hots[row,indices[row]]=values[indices[row]]
# e.g.
# n_hots[0,0]=2
# n_hots[1,3]=5
# n_hots[2,2]=4
# n_hots[3,1]=6
# Notice how the first slices are a ascending range of values:
# [0,1,2,3], and the second slice are the raveled indices, and the
# right hand side of the equal sign are the ravele values!
# That means we can just do the following:
n_hots[np.arange(4),indices]=values
print(n_hots)
```

In tensorflow it would be a bit different. First generating a `one_hot` tensor that have ones at the 2nd axis value: at the indices, and then multiplying that with the corresponding indices:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

indices=tf.placeholder(shape=(None),dtype=tf.int32)
values=tf.placeholder(shape=(None),dtype=tf.float32)
one_hots=tf.one_hot(indices, tf.shape(indices)[0])
n_hots=one_hots*tf.gather(values, indices)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    _values = np.array([[2, 5],\
                       [4, 6]])
    _indices = np.array([[0, 3],\
                        [2, 1]])
    n_h=sess.run(n_hots, {indices: _indices.ravel(), values:_values.ravel()})
    print(n_h)
```

Comment: Working on a tensorflow version now

Comment: Hello dear Andreas and thank you so much for answering my question. Its exactly that I wanted. Your method is completely correct but I can not use numpy and ravel function. Everything must be in Tensorflow. I work on your code to see that how can I do that in tensorflow but could you please have a look at that too?

Comment: I added my snippet to previous question. You are very good in coding of Tensorflow, do you have any suggestion for learning that language easily (I mean its functions and writing customized codes ?)

Comment: @HamedMozaffari Thanks for the kind words. I think the first step of getting a hold of Tensorflow is to get really comfortable with Numpy. When you know how to do something in Numpy, then it's easier to write it into Tensorflow code. The most difficult thing with tensorflow is probably that it is a symbolic programming language. That means that the code is "not executed" when you write it. If you're doing general machine learning stuff, you could start out with [Keras](https://keras.io/), which is a little bit more high-level.